# SSH help, can't connect to home machine from other home machine

Tags: networking, ssh

I have a desktop pc that I use as a dedicated host for games for friends. I recently had to do a full wipe and am having the hardest time getting ssh to work again.

I followed this old guide https://linuxhint.com/secure-ssh-server-ubuntu/ but cannot get the

```
sudo sshd –T
```

command to work for anything and for once I just don't understand what my google searching is telling me.  I've been trying to figure that part out for two days now, about two hours each day put into this, but since thats just verifying I've skipped that and continued.

I also configured the firewall on the machine using this (changing my custom_SSH_Port obviously).

```
sudo ufw allow custom_SSH_Port/tcp
```

I want to get to the SSH private/public key part but can't get connected to the machine from putty and am beating my head at this wall. I have restarted SSH.  When I try to connect it responds asking for my username, but won't allow me with the same password I use on the host machine, but nothing, connection refused and it sucks.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu Server or Desktop on the PC?

Comment: What exactly happens when you run `sudo sshd –T`? Have you verified that you can connect via ssh on the host itself ex. `ssh username@localhost`?